# I have got error in eclipse Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Course.main(Course.java:7)

Tags: java

```
public class Course {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String name="",course="",marks="";
        System.out.println("Enter the name");
        name=System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the course");
        course=System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the marks");
        marks=System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println("the Name is"+name);
    }
}
```

But it works fine if compiled with cmd

Comment: `System.console()` is returning `null`, which means you're running without a system console.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels let's leave both there! I've actually never spotted that "edit" link before...

Comment: @AndyTurner: that's because it's a new feature [as of yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels good, I've not simply been feature-blind for the past couple of years :)